# Как получить значение с callback функции?

Tags: javascript, callback, indexeddb

Есть некий запрос  к IndexedDB

```
function GetData(storename,index,callback) 
    {
        var openReq = indexedDB.open("catalogs");
        openReq.onsuccess = function() 
        {


            var db = openReq.result;
            var transaction = db.transaction([storename], "readwrite");
            var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storename);
            var objectStoreRequest = objectStore.get(index);
            var store=null;  
              objectStoreRequest.onsuccess =function(event)
              {
              store =objectStoreRequest.result;


              return store;
              }
              transaction.oncomplete = function(event)
              {
                db.close();
                if(callback)
                    callback(store);
              }
        }
    }
```

Я хочу записать значение в какуюто переменную вот так:

```
var result;
GetData('pesticides',i,function(res){result=res;  });  
console.log(result);
```

Но значение result вне области видимости и в консоль возвращается undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ужасное форматирование кода, никакого `codestyle` это раз. Во вторых нет проверки что `typeof callback === 'function'` это два. Используйте промисы и promises api. Придется переписать код функции под промисы.

```
function GetData (storename, index) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var openReq = indexedDB.open("catalogs")

    openReq.onsuccess = function () {
      var db = openReq.result
      var transaction = db.transaction([storename], "readwrite")
      var objectStore = transaction.objectStore (storename)
      var objectStoreRequest = objectStore.get (index)
      var store = null

      objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
        store = objectStoreRequest.result
        resolve(store)
      }
      transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
        db.close()
        resolve(store)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Потом в коде где надо получить результат пишите

```
GetData('sss', 2).then(function (data) {
  //в data лежит результат resolve(store)
}, function () {
  //Обработка ошибки
})
```

Не забывайте что код асинхронный

п.с. в коде возможно ошибки есть, кажется не закрыл скобку
п.с.с Я не знаю как работает ваш код, но мне кажется там очень много лишних переменных

Comment: еще можно добавить события типа `onfail` и там вызвать `reject()` который вызвовет фейловый коллбэк промиса

Comment: Я знаю что код ужасный, но нет времени на красоту. Что такое codestyle?
 Создавал переменные как в примере в документации к IndexedDB, можно запрос и в одну строчку прописать.
 Спасибо за критику и советы, сейчас буду изучать промисы.

Comment: @lischuk установите `eslint` `npm i -g eslint` потом инициализируйте `eslint init` выберите `standart`. Он будет жестко ругать за несоответсвие кода стилю

Answer (score 0):

Так не получится.

Чтобы работало или метод должен быть синхронным (плохо, плохо, плохо!) или result должен быть глобальным, относительно callback'а, а еще лучше перенести по возможности обработку в колбэк.

```
var result; 
function processResult(resultData) {
// ..
}

GetData('pesticides', i, processResult);
```